# Multiple runs of my shiny app hosted on server

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app that runs well and is hosted on a server.
To run the app requires a username/password and then the input parameters to the model, and then a submit button to run the app and get the model's outputs.

Here is my question:
A user would like to run hundreds of scenarios using the app.
Each scenario requires different values of the input parameters.
But it is very time consuming trying to run these manually via  GUI.

Is it possible to specify these inputs as a list and then run the app/browser
via loop from command line or within R?

I have looked online but can't find any solution yet

Comment: I think a better solution would be to move the server code into an R script as one big function with all the input parameters needed, create a list that captures all the combinations of inputs desired, and then run the script in a separate session, saving the output on disk to provide back to the client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you will have to change your app accordingly to take such a list as input and then perform your calculations based on such a list.

If you can not change the app itself, a macro recorder might help you to automate the user input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).